# Extracting Trees/DAG from a cyclic graph

Tags: graph, tree, directed-acyclic-graphs, cyclic-graph

Given a directed cyclic graph, how do I get various DAGs/trees, which are representative of the input graph? In effect, I'd like to extract various trees from the given circuit (directed & cyclic) graph.

Answer (score 0):

Use Prim or Kruskal's algos.
See summary: http://www.csse.monash.edu.au/~lloyd/tildeAlgDS/Graph/Undirected/

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your requirement. If you only want to have the highest weight DAG, I think you can try to sort all the edges, then remove edges one by one in that order if the edge breaks a cycle.